# Is there anything like Nanny that's still being developed?

Tags: 12.04, time, parental-controls

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for my kids to use. I am concerned about how long they use the PC each day.

Is anyone aware of any parental time-limit apps, like Gnome Nanny or timekpr, that are still active and will work with Precise?

I've found SelfControl but I'm looking for more than just internet access restriction.

For now, I am acting as the 'time keeper' until I find a software solution but thanks for any ideas.

Thank you.